# Deep Learning Variation of NNMF

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, clustering, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I'm aware that there are different variations of non negative matrix factorization based on the optimization function and I have read about graph regularized NMF. Is there any method to use deep learning to enhance the NMF results. Why have so many approaches been developed? What makes NMF so difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious reasons regarding what makes NMF difficult is because the optimization function is non-convex and thus there is no simple way to reach the global minima. Apart from that as you may already know that the factorization is not unique, there exists more than one solution to the decompose the matrix since we can consider:
$$
X=WH \implies X= WDD^{-1}H \implies X= (WD)(D^{-1}H)
$$
There have been several attempts to build a neural net based NMF model. The primary reason of creating these approaches is that there exists an inherent problem with using the basic NMF model. The basic NMF models assumes that the signals can be efficiently approximated by the linear combination of its constituents which fails in case of complicated signals.

You can refer to these papers to know more about the neural net based approaches.

1. [A Deep Semi-NMF Model for Learning Hidden Representations](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/trigeorgis14.pdf)
2. [A Deep Non-Negative Matrix Factorization Neural Network](http://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/BHunter/papers/deepNMF.pdf)

If you are using python then there is a theano based implementation of the method given in paper 1 by its author which is available in [github](https://github.com/trigeorgis/Deep-Semi-NMF).